# How to use 'proxy_pass'?

Tags: javascript, java, apache, nginx, server

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server{
        listen 3001;
        server_name localhost;

        location /{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            return 200 'OK';

        }
    }
}
```

I wrote is like this to receive 'http://localhost:3001' and send to 'http://localhost:3002'. receiving doing well. always return 200 and ok
But, my 'http://localhost:3002' does not receive any request msg.
I thought, open 'localhost:3001' in my browser, 'localhost:3002' receive anything.
Of course, when i open 'localhost:3002', i checked that my localhost:3002 receive some msg. 
Is my code wrong?

Comment: Remove `return` directive

Comment: God send you to save me